# How to make Query with IN in WHERE clause run faster

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g

I have this query in Oracle11g :

```
SELECT DOC_ID,DOC_NAME,DESC
FROM TABLE1
WHERE DOC_ID NOT IN(
    SELECT DOC_ID FROM TABLE2
)
```

The sql query above run very slow since i have so many data in the tables.
Is there any solution to get the same result with better performance and run faster?
Any help much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the query plan?  What is "very slow"?  How quickly do you need it to run?  How big are the tables?  You could potentially rewrite this as a `not exists` but if the statistics are accurate and you're really using 11g, the optimizer would probably do that rewrite internally for you.

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave. using `not exists` is faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `WHERE EXISTS` may have better performance:

```
SELECT DOC_ID,DOC_NAME,DESCr
FROM TABLE1 t1
WHERE not exists (
    SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 where
    doc_id = t1.doc_id
);
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b59e/3

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the in statement for that. If you join on what I imagine is one of your keys it should be much much faster:

```
select tb1.DOC_ID, tb1.DOC_NAME, tb1.DESC 
from table1 tb1 
left join table2 tb2 
on tb1.DOC_ID = tb2.DOC_ID
where tab2.DOC_ID is not null
```